# Using log base 10 in a formula in Java

Tags: java, logarithm

I'm trying to write a Java program that can take values and put them into a formula involving log base 10.

How can I calculate log<sub>10</sub> in Java?

Comment: `Math.log(x) / Math.log(10)`

Comment: @Mysticial: That's an answer, isn't it? (Rather than a comment.)

Comment: For further information, look up the "change of base" formula.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

It looks like Java actually has a [`log10`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log10%28double%29) function:

```
Math.log10(x)
```

Otherwise, just use math:

```
Math.log(x) / Math.log(10)
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Comment: Java 1.5 has been out of date for six years. I updated the answer to refer to something current.

Comment: 4 minutes after the [answer of Louis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13694156/589259) that contained exactly this answer. That's a bit of a shame.

Answer (score 6):

```
Math.log10(x)
```

suffices for floating-point numbers.

If you need integer log base 10, and you can use third-party libraries, Guava provides [`IntMath.log10(int, RoundingMode)`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.6-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/math/IntMath.html#log10-int-java.math.RoundingMode-).  (Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

Answer (score 0):

the below complete example may help you

```
public class Log10Math {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Method returns logarithm of number argument with base ten(10);
        short shortVal = 10;
        byte byteVal = 1;
        double doubleVal = Math.log10(byteVal);

        System.out.println("Log10 Results");
        System.out.println(Math.log10(1));
        System.out.println(doubleVal);
        System.out.println(Math.log10(shortVal));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Log10 Results
0.0
0.0
1.0
```

Comment: Follow the Java Naming Conventions, variable names start with lowercase.

Comment: @MCEmperor, thanks for the inputs, updated my answer.

Comment: That's better! ;-)

Answer (score -1):

in Java we can use log function as that. 
(int) Math.log(val);
int is a type to convert it into this , in which you are storing ur answer.